# Read kernel messages during boot before crash

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, boot

I am trying to debug a boot loop issue. The issue disappear if I add `acpi=off` to my kernel parameters with Grub, and I am trying to understand why.

However, when I boot the computer without this parameter, the kernel displays its boot message very quickly, then the computer reboots. The whole thing happen in less than a second. It is so fast I am unable to read the messages, even by filming the screen. The errors seems to happen before mounting the disk in rw mode, so no log is saved.

What is a robust solution to be able to read the kernel messages during boot?

So far, I have tried the following kernel parameters:

- `panic=0` and `kernel.panic=0`: no effect, the computer still reboot.
- `boot_delay=200` with and without `lpj=13199976`, as advised by https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/BOOT_PRINTK_DELAY.html (the lpj value is taken from a boot with `acpi=off`) : the computer seems to freeze. I once tried with `boot_delay=4` and after some time, it "crashed normally" (the messages suddenly appear very quick and then the computer reboots).
  `CONFIG_BOOT_PRINTK_DELAY` is enabled in the kernel config.
- I suppose I could try to forward the messages via a serial port, but I do not have any adapter laying around.
- netconsole: the crash happen before the netconsole has a chance to be enabled.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on Linux 5.4.0-52-generic.